# will the setImmediate or the IO callback run first?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callstack, event-loop

in this diagram is says that the event Loop will run the I/O callbacks (the axios request), then the check phase (setImmediate), but when i tested this, it was the opposite, i need explanation of the execution of that code.

[image: diagram]
[image]

Comment: The axios.get just takes too much time and is completed in one of next iterations.

Comment: does that mean, it's not in the queue yet, do you mean that it will be added to the queue once it gets the http response?

Comment: You log `promise` only when the IO is resolved. I doubt it would ever make it before `immediate`.

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log('first'); // logs instantly 

setImmediate(() => console.log('immediate')); // will be executed in the next iteration of the event loop.

new Promise((resolve) => { // starts in promise in pending state
  console.log('insidePromise');
  const data = 'Promise';
  resolve(data);
}).then((d) => console.log(d)); // prints after Promise is resolved
```

Output -

```
first
insidePromise
Promise
immediate
```

When the Promise is called it starts in a pending state and waiting for resolve.

setImmediate - triggers here before resolve is processed as `setImmediate` will have to be executed in the event loop.

https://nodejs.dev/learn/understanding-javascript-promises

> Once a promise has been called, it will start in a pending state. This means that the calling function continues executing, while the promise is pending until it resolves, giving the calling function whatever data was being requested.

https://nodejs.dev/learn/understanding-setimmediate

> Any function passed as the setImmediate() argument is a callback that's executed in the next iteration of the event loop.